# jquery ajax - calling my asp.net web api gives a wrong url and a 404 not found message

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm writing a small ASP.NET MVC site which also includes a WEB API in it that I wrote.

I've configured the project on my local IIS as `http://localhost/mysite`

On the main page of my site I'm including a js script that I wrote:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/js/home.js")"></script>
```

on the page ready event of that js I call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'api/getdetails',
    accepts: 'application/json',
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

when looking with Fidler I see that the page call returns a 404 since it doesn't try to load it to the relative path I'm in (`http://localhost/mysite`) and it tries to load the root of the server - so the call looks like this `http://localhost:80/api/getdetails`

when I was writing web forms I used to do ajax calls such as this all the time and it always worked.

what am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Web API is a REST based system. Try to dig a little deeper into REST and embrace its mindset. Naming the controller "GetDetails" is not restful and it's repetitive too.

Comment: @timmkrause thanks - i'll take that into consideration - however, this is not what's causing the problem...

Comment: what output url is `@Url.Content("...")` like you state in your post, giving? interested in he url pattern...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What I ended up doing is in my layout html I've added a js var:

```
var baseUrl = '@Url.Content("~/")';
```

then on my ajax call I've added that base url:

```
$.ajax({
    url: baseUrl + 'api/getdetails',
    accepts: 'application/json',
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

this does the trick no matter how the page looks like. even if I navigate to `http://localhost/mysite/home/index`

It's probably not the perfect solution, and I definitely think the old webforms way which worked was better - but I guess there are pros and cons to any technology.

Still would be happy to hear if someone has a better solution. for now - this does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to

```
http://localhost/mysite
```

The behavior is a little different from

```
http://localhost/mysite/
```

Try that to confirm. Without the trailing slash, the "mysite" looks like a document name, not a folder, so relative paths would form from the root of the server.

What you may need to do is pass in the site content URL into your `home.js` and form absolute paths from it in your code.